# How to get value of a key from a returned array from Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel, auto-increment

A raw query in Laravel is returning the below output when I print_r() it.

> Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [AUTO_INCREMENT] => 28 ) )

How can I extract just the value of AUTO_INCREMENT? In this example, the value being 28.

Comment: $response[0]->AUTO_INCREMENT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value is a property from a stdClass.

Lets say you have this:

```
$result; \\your ex
echo $result[0]->AUTO_INCREMENT; \\this would echo 28.
```

You can read more here [how to fetch property from object](http://php.net/manual/en/sdo.sample.getset.php)